# Android ionic hybrid app missing SalesforceOAuthPlugin

Tags: oauth, sfdcmobilesdk-android, cordova

I'm trying to buid a simple android SFDC app using Ionic, I used this https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-salesforce when I try it in the browser using ForceServer it works fine but when I try to use it on an android  device (Samsung phone) it does not work, there is a white screen flash and nothing.

Using adb logcat I could find the error:

```
W/System.err(25738): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.SalesforceOAuthPlugin

W/System.err(25738):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

W/System.err(25738):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)

W/System.err(25738):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)

W/System.err(25738):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.instantiatePlugin(PluginManager.java:345)

W/System.err(25738):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:189)

W/System.err(25738):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:137)

W/System.err(25738):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)

W/System.err(25738):    at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)

W/System.err(25738):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)

W/System.err(25738):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)

W/System.err(25738):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

W/System.err(25738):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)

W/System.err(25738):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

W/System.err(25738): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/salesforce/androidsdk/phonegap/SalesforceOAuthPlugin

W/System.err(25738):    ... 13 more

W/System.err(25738): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.SalesforceOAuthPlugin" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ionicframework.marmara789813-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ionicframework.marmara789813-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

W/System.err(25738):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

W/System.err(25738):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)

W/System.err(25738):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)

W/System.err(25738):    ... 13 more

I/System.out(25738): Error adding plugin com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.SalesforceOAuthPlugin.

W/System.err(25738): java.lang.NullPointerException

W/System.err(25738):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:191)

W/System.err(25738):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:137)

W/System.err(25738):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)

W/System.err(25738):    at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)

W/System.err(25738):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)

W/System.err(25738):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)

W/System.err(25738):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

W/System.err(25738):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)

W/System.err(25738):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

in my plugins directory I do have the com.salesforce package